# Prove number of single color triangles in complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, coloring, ramsey-theory

**Problem:**
Let $K_n$ be a complete graph with $n$ nodes. Let $n \ge 6$.
Prove that if we color this graph with two colors, then there will be at least:
${n\choose 3} / {6\choose 3}$ single color triangles.

**Question:**
How can I prove that? I suppose that I should make use of Ramsey's theorem. But I'm not sure how to prove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider all $6$-vertex subgraphs of $K_n$. Each of them has at least one monochromatic triangle, so at least a fraction $\frac1{\binom63}$ of its triangles are monochromatic. If you average this fraction over all these subgraphs, the result is again at least $\frac1{\binom63}$. In this average, you count all triangles in $K_n$ the same number of times, so the resulting average fraction of monochromatic triangles is the same as in the entire graph. The entire graph has $\binom n3$ triangles, so at least $\frac{\binom n3}{\binom 63}$ of them are monochromatic.